# Metric spaces, continuous functions

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $f,g: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous in $a \in M$. If $f(a)<g(a)$, $ \ \exists \delta>0$ such that, for all $x,y \in M$ $$d(x,a)<\delta, d(y,a)<\delta \rightarrow f(x)<g(y) $$.

I Just can't find the right $\delta$ for the problem.

Comment: Is that all of the information that you have for the problem?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I assume it is that "If $d(x, a) < \delta$ and $d(y, a) < \delta$, show that $f(x) < g(y)$".
All the conditional statement is saying is that both $x$ and $y$ are contained in a $\delta$ neighborhood about $a$. I would think we would need to know more about $f,g$?

Comment: That's all the question says.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon =\frac {g(a)-f(a)} 2$. There exist $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a))| <\epsilon$ if $d(x,a) <\delta$ and $|g(y)-g(a)| <\epsilon$  if $d(y,a) <\delta$. Now if $d(x,a) <\delta$ and $d(y,a) <\delta$ then $f(x) <f(a)+\epsilon =g(a)-\epsilon <g(y)$.